# How can I pass the input box value on clicking anchor tag to php?

Tags: php, html

I want to pass the value for each rows to php page to update in database I am able to pass only id not the input box value

This is the table body

```
  <?php
  $cards = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Username, Card_No, Card_Status FROM 
  smartcard WHERE Card_Status NOT IN (SELECT Card_Status FROM smartcard where Card_Status = 'Issued')");
  ?>
 <tbody>
        <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cards))
        {
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                echo '<td style="word-wrap: break-word;min-width: 10px;max-width: 300px;">',$value,'</td>';
            }            
            echo '<td><form action="php/issue_card.php" method="POST"><input id="textbox" name="new_status" type="text" class="form-control" required="required"/></form></td>';
            echo "<td><a href='php/issue_card.php?id=".$row['Card_No']."'><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-link\">Status Update</button></a></td>";
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?>
 </tbody>
```

This is the php page issue_card.php

```
 <?php
  include("connect.php");
  $con = OpenCon();
  $smartcard_no = $_GET['id'];
  $admin_id = $_SESSION['Admin_Id'];
  $new_status = $_POST['new_status'];
  $sql = "UPDATE smartcard SET Card_Status = '$new_status', Admin_Id ='$admin_id' WHERE smartcard.smartcard_no = $smartcard_no";
   mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  CloseCon($con);
  ?>
```

For each row there will be different smartcard_no so I am using anchor tag to pass that directly using GET but not able to pass input box value.

Comment: You are generating invalid html. The `form` MUST either be within a table cell `td` or the entire table should be within the form - the latter is not suitable for your use-case so the form ought to be within the table cell

Comment: @RamRaider i tried that but still in php i m getting same error unindexed new_status.

Comment: The `a` with the querystring will not POST the form but will issue a GET request to the page `page_issue.php` ~ there are a couple of solutions that come to mind. [a] use one form for the entire table and have two hidden fields that you populate with javascript before the form is submitted [b] assign the button as a `submit` button and have the `id` as a hidden field

Comment: I dono anything about javascript. Can you please tell more about the second solution?

Comment: Your submit button needs to be inside the form. The button click makes a GET request to `php/issue_card.php`, which means that the `$_POST` array will be empty, and `new_status` will be an invalid index.

Comment: If i change the method type to GET and i if try $_GET i get the same error @J.D.Pace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a quickly written ( and not tested ) example of the 2nd idea - where there is just one form that encompasses the entire table and has two hidden fields for the important pieces of data that you wish to POST to the PHP script.

Each button within the table is assigned an event handler - the event handler in this case will query the DOM to find the text field within the same row and then assign that value and the value found in the buttons own `data-id` attribute o the hidden input fields before submitting the form.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(e){

        /* Obtain a reference to the FORM element */
        var form=document.forms['status-updates'];      

        /* Hidden fields which will be POSTed to php/issue_card.php */
        var id=form.querySelector('input[type="hidden"][name="id"]');
        var status=form.querySelector('input[type="hidden"][name="new_status"]');



        /* Create a nodelist collection of ALL buttons within table of class "bttn" */
        var col=Array.prototype.slice.call( form.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"].bttn') );

        /* Assign event handler to each button */
        col.forEach( function( bttn ){
            bttn.onclick=function(e){/* - event handler - */

                /* Assign values to hidden fields */
                id.value=this.dataset.id;
                status.value=this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;

                /* submit the form with values for this row */
                form.submit();
            }.bind( bttn );
        });
    },false );
</script>

<form name='status-updates' method='post' action='php/issue_card.php'>
    <!-- two hidden fields -->
    <input type='hidden' name='id' />
    <input type='hidden' name='new_status' />

    <table>
        <?php
            while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $cards ) ) {
                echo "
                <tr>";

                foreach( $row as $key => $value ) echo "
                    <td class='wrap'>{$value}</td>";

                echo "
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' class='form-control' required='required' />
                        <input type='button' value='Status Update' class='bttn' data-id='{$row['Card_No']}' />
                    </td>
                </tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried above code there is no effect on clicking the button.

Comment: admin_approve_cards.php:120 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (admin_approve_cards.php:120)

Comment: 120th line is this  
   status.value=this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type="text"][name="tmp_new_status"]').value;

Comment: Check the version of the code that is here now... I edited that when I did some testing

Comment: Now nothing is coming in console and the button still not working

Comment: as a test, just before `form.submit()` put `alert( form+' '+id.value+' '+status.value );`

Comment: Still the same problem :(

Comment: Does the alert popup with 3 values?

Comment: I didnt get any popups actually.

Comment: There must be a syntax error somewhere then. Open the console and do a page refresh to see if there are any errors listed. Can you do a Pastebin dump of the actual code and share the link?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/RFvYxB9G admin_approve_cards.php  https://pastebin.com/4zzt56Xf issue_card.php

Comment: OK - the html is again Invalid. As I mentioned in the 1st comment, either the form MUST be contained within a table cell or the form MUST contain the entire table. As you have it now the table starts and then you have a form in a non-valid location within the html.

Comment: You can now safely delete the `alert()` statement if it is working OK..

Comment: good stuff - glad it helped. Hope you have understood the javascript and could utilise some of that in future projects

Answer (score 1):

```
      <?php
      $cards = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Username, Card_No, Card_Status FROM 
      smartcard WHERE Card_Status NOT IN (SELECT Card_Status FROM smartcard where Card_Status = 'Issued')");
      ?>
     <tbody>
<form>
            <?php
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cards))
            {
                echo '<tr>';
                foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                    echo '<td style="word-wrap: break-word;min-width: 10px;max-width: 300px;">',$value,'</td>';
                }            
                echo '<td><input class="textbox" name="new_status" type="text" class="form-control" required="required"/></td>';
                echo "<td><button class="updateBtn" data-id=".$row['Card_No'].">Status Update</button></a></td>";
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            ?>
     </tbody>


<script>
/*import jquery before using this.*/


$(document).ready(function(){

$('.updateBtn').on('click',function(){
var status=$(this).parent().find('.textbox').val()
var id=$(this).attr('data-id');
sendData(status,id)

})

function sendData(status,id){
$.ajax({
url:'php/issue_card.php',
data:{status:status,id:id},
type:'get' //get or post,
success:function(success){
//callback
},
error:function(error){
//error callback
}
})



}

})


</script>
```

Comment: http://localhost/MyProject/admin_approve_cards.php?new_status=swar&new_status=&new_status=&new_status= i m seeing this in address bar it should go to issue_card.php , in address cardno is not going too and i want only particular row's input box value not other rows ....thank you

Comment: use card number in another parameter just like other is going through.